# How to get the property of father in this example?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

```
var father = {
  b: 3,
  c: 4
};

var child = Object.create(father);
child.a = 1;
child.b = 2;
```

child.b is now 2, chrome devtools shows that child has b property that is inherited. How do I get to it, and why it is not overriden?

Comment: what you are trying to do? looks confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects in javascript has a link to other Objects called `__proto__`. You can get the properties of parent object using this:

```js
var father = {
  b: 3,
  c: 4
};

var child = Object.create(father);
child.a = 1;
child.b = 2;
console.log(child);//prints Object { a: 1, b: 2 }
console.log(child.__proto__);//prints Object { b: 3, c: 4 }
```

> You can use this secret property for learning purposes, but it's not a
>   good idea to use it in your real scripts because it does not exist in
>   all browsers (notably Internet Explorer), so your scripts won't be
>   portable.
>
> Be aware that `__proto__` is not the same as prototype, since
>   `__proto__` is a property of the instances (objects), whereas
>   prototype is a property of the constructor functions used to create
>   those objects. [ 1 ]

I strongly suggest to use Object.getPrototypeOf():

```js
var father = {
  b: 3,
  c: 4
};

var child = Object.create(father);
child.a = 1;
child.b = 2;
console.log(child);//prints Object { a: 1, b: 2 }
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(child));//prints Object { b: 3, c: 4 }
```

**Reference**

[Object-Oriented JavaScript - Second Edition](https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/object-oriented-javascript-second-edition)  [ 1 ]

Comment: `Object.getPrototypeOf` is not just an "alternative", it's the only correct thing to do. `__proto__` is deprecated and should no longer be advertised.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way, but you need to read a little bit more about shadowing and inheritance and prototype chain.

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(child).b
```